# How to turn nested plain js objects into Ember.js objects?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

If I have a nested set of plain old javascript objects (for example, having been returned from JSON), how do I them into Ember.js objects (or at least getting the binding functionality working)?

For example, if I have an object like:

```
var x = {
  bar: {
    baz: "quux"
  }
}
```

Then I turn that into an Ember object:

```
var y = Ember.Object.create(x);
```

Then setting the value of "baz" won't update any views I have, because it is just a normal js object, not an Ember object.

I know I can just recursively go over the object keys, and do Ember.Object.create all the way down, but is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you're attempting to set the value of `baz`, after you've created the `Ember.Object`, but you should make sure you use an observer-aware setter function. For this example, I'd suggest using `setPath()`.

For example:

```
var x = {
  bar: {
    baz: "quux"
  }
};
var y = Ember.Object.create(x);
y.setPath('bar.baz', 'foo');
```

jsFiddle example, showing a view update after setting: http://jsfiddle.net/ebryn/kv3cU/

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do that. I guess it is a bit messier because then you have to use 2 different accessor methods

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: Sometimes you can use standard js assignment, i.e. foo.bar = "a", but other times you need to use setPath. (I'm using ENV.USE_ACCESSORS = true, because I don't need to care about IE).

Comment: `set` now supports paths. So there's no need to use `setPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version:

```
import { typeOf } from '@ember/utils'
import EmberObject from '@ember/object'

export default function deepEmberObject(anything) {
  if (typeOf(anything) === 'array') {
    return anything.map(a => deepEmberObject(a))
  } else if (typeOf(anything) === 'object') {
    let converted = Object.keys(anything).reduce((acc, k) => {
      acc[k] = deepEmberObject(anything[k])
      return acc
    }, {})
    return EmberObject.create(converted)
  } else {
    return anything
  }
}
```

test:

```
import deepEmberObject from 'zipbooks/utils/deep-ember-object'
import { module, test } from 'qunit'

module('Unit | Utility | deep-ember-object', function() {
  test('it works', function(assert) {
    let result = deepEmberObject({ pandas: [{ id: 3, children: [{ name: 'Bobby', features: { weight: 3 } }] }] })
    assert.equal(
      result
        .get('pandas')[0]
        .get('children')[0]
        .get('features')
        .get('weight'),
      3
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, this was very helpful. As a side note for the reader, `Ember.typeOf` will return `instance` or `class` for EmberObjects. So if you want to use this to deep copy ember objects, you should handle those two values in the `else if` in the same way as `object`.

https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Futils/typeOf

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I had to define nested objects independently in order to ensure the computed works properly (even the enumerated ones).

For that I end up crafting these 2 utility functions:

```
import EmberObject from '@ember/object';
import { A } from '@ember/array';

function fromArrayToEmberArray(array) {
    const emberArray = A();
    array.forEach(function(item) {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            emberArray.push(fromArrayToEmberArray(item));
        } else if (item && typeof item === 'object') {
            emberArray.push(fromObjectToEmberObject(item));
        } else {
            emberArray.push(item);
        }
    });
    return emberArray;
}

function fromObjectToEmberObject(pojo) {
    const emberObject = EmberObject.create();

    for (const key in pojo) {
        const keyObject = pojo[key];
         if (Array.isArray(keyObject)) {
            emberObject.set(key, fromArrayToEmberArray(keyObject))
        } else if (keyObject && typeof keyObject === 'object') {
            emberObject.set(key, fromObjectToEmberObject(keyObject))
        } else {
            emberObject.set(key, keyObject);
        }
    }

    return emberObject;
}

export default {fromObjectToEmberObject};
```